# Bind combobox property of selected item in combobox to field

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have an issue with binding in ComboBox. I have searched in Google and so, but I haven't been able to find the answer.

I have silverlight form with combobox like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="FirmBox"
          Grid.Row="23"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          Margin="5,5,5,0"
          SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Firm, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And the ItemsSource is an

```
ObservableCollection<KeyValue<String, KeyValue<String, String>>>
```

So I've figured out how to display this in right way, but I don't know how to bind the selected item to my `KeyValuePair<String, String>`
field. That does not seem obvious to me. So I need to bind the value of selected item to my field and don't know how to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple as always:

```
SelectedValuePath="Value"
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Firm, Mode=TwoWay}">
```